# Discussion - chess analysis thread

Tags: discussion, tags, site-scope

Can we allow posts for analysis of games by people? These can be labeled by the tag [game-analysis](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-analysis). By analysis, I mean that a person posts a chess game in a thread, and then someone else provides comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already have an [analysis](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag which is used for both specific positions and ([recent example](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/31962/7297)) complete games. The latter, while not strictly off-topic, are usually not too well received, since most of the times they are mainly useful to one person, the author of the question. Also, they tend not to be well-researched; for some examples, see the [lowest scoring questions in that tag](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis?tab=votes&page=13&pagesize=50).

Stack Exchange works best with well-researched questions and answers which are valuable to many people (including future visitors), so I do not think we should create a new tag which will mainly be used in poor and mediocre questions.